# Problem when checking expiration date using json date

Tags: python

Problem when checking expiration date using json date.

Where am I going wrong?

```
from datetime import datetime, date
datet = '2019-06-12T00:00:00+00:00'

ExpirationDate = datetime.strptime(datet, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
now = datetime.now()
if ExpirationDate >= now:
  print("ok")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    ExpirationDate = datetime.strptime(datet, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 565, in
_strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
    (data_string, format)) ValueError: time data '2019-06-12T00:00:00+00:00' does not matchformat '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in the `+00:00` at the end. In your format string it matches up until `.%f`. Either you must change your format string to include the `+` or you date to have a `.00` instead of `+00:00`.

Comment: The api where we are referring to this date returns in this format. Is there any way to do it without having to edit the string? Thanks for listening

Comment: @marcelo.delta could you link the docs that say this? Thanks.